# Is it possible to use a transition with ScrollToSection in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want a smoother jump to a HubSection in a Hub while using ScrollToSection(). Is this possible with transitions or an animation?